# MySQL substract first row from last row of a group

Tags: mysql

I'm working on creating Google Charts from MySQL datasource. This works fine so far. Now I want to count how many blocks of a Blockchain processed per hour.

**How can I simple substract the first row from last row of a group?**

```
SELECT
   date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i'),blocks,
   count(1)
FROM blockchain
GROUP BY 1  
ORDER BY `date_format(time,'%Y-%m-%d %H-%i')` ASC
```

**And if this done, how to repeat this for the last 24 hours?**

Sample data:

```
id          time                        blocks

3           2020-12-30 11:21:53         112149
4           2020-12-30 11:21:55         112150
5           2020-12-30 11:21:56         112150
6           2020-12-30 11:21:57         112150
7           2020-12-30 11:24:01         112169
8           2020-12-30 11:25:01         112178
9           2020-12-30 11:26:01         112188
10          2020-12-30 11:27:01         112197



-10         2020-12-30 11:27:01         112197
 3          2020-12-30 11:21:53         112149
-----------------------------------------------
                                        48
```

I hope its not a stupid question. I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. Your original query is not valid standard SQL (`blocks` in the `SELECT` clause is not consistent with the `GROUP BY` clause).

Comment: Thank you for your answere. I updated it with sample data,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to get blocks per hour.

```
select hour(time) as hr, max(blocks)-min(blocks) as blocks_per_hour
from test
group by hour(time)
```

Result:

> | hr | blocks_per_hour |
> | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 48 |

Example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=96ee323e8f15af0a946ff1220af01588

Comment: @nebkas if that's what you want, you are welcome to mark the answer as accepted so that others can find that your question was answered. There's a check mark beside my answer that you have to click to accept this as an answer.

Comment: Sure, I did it now :)

Comment: Now it gives me some strage values after my sql table stored data for more than 24 hours :/

https://i.ibb.co/yggpcD3/mysql.png

Comment: Try updating your query to include year, month and day also like so: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8f94c1ef579313fcdac0254b82b3ad0a